# Normal probability distribution with absolute value of X

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Random variable X has a normal distribution N(30,5)

find  $P(|X| > 25)$

Having this I started to solve it normal way:
$$P(|X| > 25) = 1 - P(|X| \le 25) $$

Now, normalize:
$$1-P(|X| \le 25) = 1 - P (\frac{|X|-30}{5} \le \frac{25-30}{5})$$

$$1-(P(x<-25)+P(X > 25)) = 1 -(P( \frac{x-30}{5} < \frac{25-30}{5})+1-P( \frac{x-30}{5} \le \frac{25-30}{5})) $$

but solving it I obtained probability of... 1.8. So something is definitely wrong.
Could you point me my mistake, please?

Comment: how did you get $1.8$?

Comment: I believe I wrongly interpeted absolute value in just added part of my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall not normalize as you are dealing with the module, so a better way is
$$
  P(|X|>25) = 1-P(|X|\leq25) = 1-P(-25\leq X\leq25)=
$$
here we put $\xi$ to be a standard normal r.v. - i.e. we do a normalization
$$
  = 1-P\left(-25\leq5\xi+30\leq 25\right) = 1-P(\xi\in[-11,-1])
$$
and the latter probability you can find easily. Note that here I assumed (as you also did) that $5$ is the deviation of $X$ and not the variance.

Comment: just simply got one more question: when normalizing why didn't you touch -25 and 25? Shouldn't it be $1-P( \frac{-25-30}{5} ... )$ and same for 25?

Comment: Ok, now I see that u did it on-the-fly. Thank you.